# Re-writing my program so it would fit the map-reduce structure

Tags: java, mapreduce, amazon-emr, inverted-index

I've written an InvertedIndex java program, where given a word, it searches the word in a certain static array of string, where each string is a url that needs to be searched on. It finally returns a list of all the url's the word was found in.

Here's my relevant code:

```
static final String[] URL_SEARCH_LIST = {
        "http://www.cnn.com", "http://www.daniel.com", "http://www.amazon.com"
    };
private static List<String> search (String query) {
        try {
            List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String site : URL_SEARCH_LIST) {
                URL url = new URL(site);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (conn.getInputStream())));
                String htmlContent;
                while ((htmlContent = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (htmlContent.contains(query)) {
                        urlList.add(site);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Search for: " + query + " Is Done!");
            return urlList;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to make this run on Amazon EMR, which means I need to convert my program to a Map-Reduce program which does the same thing.

Given this code, can someone please help me to start? I didn't fully understand the concept of map and reduce...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map-reduce is basically just divide and conquer plus a lot of infrastructure, so divide on (map) your `URL_SEARCH_LIST` array, create each local `urlList`, and combine (reduce) all of the `urlLists` for the final output

Comment: How can I determine how many maps will be? is my local urlList is the entire list every time? Can you try to give me a map-reduce code example based on mine?

Comment: Map on every url - the infrastructure will take care of all of the load-balancing.

Comment: See the word count example in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) - the map function divides on each word and lets the load balancer take care of the rest. In your case the local `urlList` is the value where in the word count example `1` is always the value.

Comment: OK So if I understand correctly, what you described takes each url and counts each word in it, how would I make it count only one given word? how would I make it count a given string instead of one word?

Comment: @user1067083 [Here is an example](http://arfon.org/getting-started-with-elastic-mapreduce-and-hadoop-streaming) of counting only a given word - it's in PHP, but it should give you an idea of how to write a similar function in Java

Comment: I'll give it a try to understand. Thanks alot.